# How do I reset/regain a root password when I din't know it?

Tags: password

I have gotten a laptop with Ubuntu installed on it. I have got an account with a password that I indeed do remember, but when I try to install some things, I cannot install it without entering the root password ( and sometimes sudo or something). The weird thing is that I am able to install a few things like OpenArena and Musescore, but I can't install other games/software like PlayOnLinux. I don't even know what root password means but I've tried entering my user password and it didn't work. The word "root" or "sudo" also doesn't work. I have no clue what this password could be. I got the laptop from someone who I can't contact at the moment. Is there any way of resetting the password or making it visible for me so I can actually do anything on this currently useless laptop? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to enter your username password as root password? if this is your personal computer then this might have been set up as part of the initial configurartion, if this is a PC provided by your job or some other entity, then you don't have access to being super user. You will have to ask IT or your admin to install it for you.

Comment: If you do not know and trust the person who installed Ubuntu on your system, and it really is *your* system, then wipe and reinstall.

Comment: I've already tried my username password. The laptop is indeed provided by my job. Do you think there is really no other way than asking IT? I've also tried via GRUB, but when I try to edit the parameters or something else it asks for a username+password and I can't even write numbers or use backspace on there for some reason

Comment: @Bobba If this is truly a device provided by your job, I am absolutely certain that they would rather you ask for the password, or ask them to reset it.  I'm sure that they DO NOT want you hacking away at it uninformed/unskilled. It's likely they don't want you to install any new software without their permission.  You could expose them to liabilities.

Comment: Per your comments: this device was issued by your workplace.  **Tampering with the device including obtaining root password permissions and other permissions outside your permitted levels of access is most likely a violation of your corporate terms of use, and in some jurisdictions may be against the law.**  You need to coordinate with your IT people at your if you need assistance with a workplace-issued device, not attempt to bypass configurations that they've put into place.